# Add the SID to a .csv File with aduser Object from Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a .csv File looking like that:

```
"UserName" , "GroupName"
"t123","G-Q-TAT"
"t124","G-Q-ABC"
"t234","G-Q-ABD"
```

I want in Powershell creating an addionional column containing the SID.

So it should look like that:

```
"UserName" , "GroupName" , "SID" 
"t123","G-Q-TAT","S-1-5-21-2079806555-1600217444-939750222-15100"
"t124","G-Q-ABC","S-1-5-21-2079806555-1600217444-939750222-15101"
"t234","G-Q-ABD","S-1-5-21-2079806555-1600217444-939750222-15102"
```

I tried the following:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Csv c:\users.csv|foreach{
get-aduser $_.UserName -properties objectsid , samaccountname |select samaccountname, objectsid , @{l="GroupName";e={$item.GroupName}}
}|export-csv "C:\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Everything works fine, except the groupname is not given out anymore. What did I wrong? Thank you a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to declare the `$item` variable:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
@(foreach($item in Import-Csv c:\users.csv){
    Get-ADUser $item.UserName -properties objectsid,samaccountname |select samaccountname,objectsid,@{l="GroupName";e={$item.GroupName}}
}) |Export-Csv "C:\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Cool! Yes that worked fine! Thank you a lot. Problem solved!